# How to purify volatile haloalkanes prepared by Darzens halogenation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, purification

We know that the [Darzens method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darzens_halogenation) of substitution works on $S_n i$ and is considered the best method in terms of yield of product. Also the side products are $\ce{SO_2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$ so the equilibrium shifts in the forward direction. But we know the lower haloalkanes are gases so if the molecular masses of the halides are comparable with that of the side products then how can we purify them since we cannot use Grahm's Law of Diffuson.

Comment: Sir @Jan I have tried to improve by posting a link. I m just an beginner. Please help

Comment: At least I understood what the method is supposed to be, and ron took care of the tags (thanks!) I'm still voting to close as unclear because I don't know about your specific case.

Comment: If you bubble the product gas stream through water that will remove the $\ce{HCl}$.  There is probably a similar process that will remove the $\ce{SO2}$, perhaps bubbling the gas stream through a tube of  $\ce{CaCO3}$.

Comment: If they're low boiling, aren't you just going to purify by distillation anyway?

Comment: @Zhe But Both of the haloalkanes are volatile and the boiling points are also comparable.

Comment: Then you can't separate them...